# Subroutes done right with app-route

Tags: javascript, routes, polymer

I have this in my app.js in terms of routing:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>

<app-route 
  route="{{route}}"
  pattern="/page/:page"
  data="{{routeData}}"
  tail="{{subRoute}}">
</app-route>
```

As in the starter kit, I observe `routeData.page` to make sure that this.page is synced.

```
 ...
 observers: [
    '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)',
  ],

  _routePageChanged: function(page) {
    this.page = page;
  }
  ...
```

I then create two pages, selected with iron-pages:

```
  <iron-pages id="pageSelector" role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="view404">

      <my-offers-made
          title="Offers made"
          name="offers-made"
          user-data="{{userData}}"
          site-info="{{siteInfo}}"
          route="{{subRoute}}">
        </my-offers-made>

    <my-chat
          title="Chat"
          name="chat"
          user-data="{{userData}}"
          site-info="{{siteInfo}}"
          route="{{subRoute}}">
        </my-chat>
  </iron-pages>
```

**NOTE**: Potential mistake: they both share `subRoute`.

`my-chat` might display either a list of active conversations, or messages with a specific user. So, in `my-chat` I have:

```
<app-route
  route="{{route}}"
  pattern="/:userId"
  data="{{routeData}}"
  active="{{active}}">
</app-route>
```

Then, `my-chat` just checks what to display depending on `userId`.

`my-offers-made` has different tabs. So:

```
<app-route 
  route="{{route}}"
  pattern="/:tab"
  data="{{routeData}}">
</app-route>
```

And it will display the right tab.

**THE PROBLEM** is that if I change tab in `my-offers-made`, and then go to `my-chat`, `routeData.userid` *is polluted with the tab name from `my-offers-made`* since they share `subRoute`.

I am obviously doing something *very* wrong. Do I absolutely have to make up different tails for each route, so that they don't pollute each other?

```
<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/page/:page" data="{{routeData}}"></app-route>

<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/page/chat" data="{{routeData}}" tail="{{subRouteChat}}"></app-route>

<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/page/my-offers-made" data="{{routeData}}" tail="{{subRouteOffersMade}}"></app-route>
```

...? Or am I missing something totally huge here?

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be caused by the fact that your child `<app-route>` elements have identical `pattern`s, so both `<app-route>`s would always have a matching `route` and `routeData`. A workaround would be to make the `pattern`s different in each child (e.g., insert a simple prefix):

```
// my-chat: prefix userid with /u/
<app-route route="{{route}}"
           pattern="/u/:userId"
           data="{{routeData}}">
</app-route>

// my-offers-made: prefix tab name with /t/
<app-route route="{{route}}"
           pattern="/t/:tab"
           data="{{routeData}}">
</app-route>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-app',
    properties: {
      route: {
        type: Object,
        value: () => ({ path: '/page/offers-made/t/foo' })
      }
    },
    _gotoMyOffers: function() {
      this.set('route.path', '/page/offers-made');
    },
    _gotoChat: function() {
      this.set('route.path', '/page/chat');
    }
  });
  
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-offers-made'
  });
  
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-chat'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
  <link rel="import" href="app-route/app-route.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
</head>

<body>
  <my-app></my-app>

  <dom-module id="my-app">
    <template>
      <span>Enter <code>/page/offers-made/t/<b>TABNAME</b></code> or <code>/page/chat/u/<b>USERID</b></code></span>
      <paper-input value="{{route.path}}" label="Location"></paper-input>

      <app-route route="{{route}}"
                 pattern="/page/:page"
                 data="{{routeData}}"
                 tail="{{subRoute}}">
      </app-route>
      <button on-tap="_gotoChat">Show Chat</button>
      <button on-tap="_gotoMyOffers">Show Offers</button>

      <iron-pages id="pageSelector" role="main" selected="[[routeData.page]]" attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="view404">

        <my-offers-made
            title="Offers made"
            name="offers-made"
            user-data="{{userData}}"
            site-info="{{siteInfo}}"
            route="{{subRoute}}">
        </my-offers-made>

        <my-chat
            title="Chat"
            name="chat"
            user-data="{{userData}}"
            site-info="{{siteInfo}}"
            route="{{subRoute}}">
        </my-chat>

        <div name="view404">Sorry, page not found!</div>
      </iron-pages>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-offers-made">
    <template>
      <app-route route="{{route}}"
                 pattern="/t/:tab"
                 data="{{routeData}}">
      </app-route>
      <h2>my-offers-made</h2>
      <paper-input label="routeData.tab" value="{{routeData.tab}}"></paper-input>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="my-chat">
    <template>
      <app-route route="{{route}}"
                 pattern="/u/:userId"
                 data="{{routeData}}"
                 active="{{active}}">
      </app-route>
      <h2>my-chat</h2>
      <paper-input label="routeData.userId" value="{{routeData.userId}}"></paper-input>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/WoxMeR?editors=1010)